# Why am I getting Unhandled Promise Error using express-validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am running into an issue with handling errors with express-validator with an api I am building.  I got it to work, but I don't understand why the initial code does not work and wondering if someone can explain it for me?

I use the express-validator check middleware on my routes like below:

```
   router.put(
      "/sign-up",
      [
        check("name", "Invalid Name").trim().isLength({ min: 1 }),
        check("email", "Invalid Email")
          .isEmail()
          .isLength({ min: 1 })
          .normalizeEmail(),
      ],
      userController.putUser
    );
```

Then in the controller I have the below code to handle in case there is an error:

```
     exports.putUser = async (req, res, next) => {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        // const err = new Error("Validation Failed!");
        // err.data = errors.array();
        // err.statusCode = 422;
        // throw err;
        return res
          .status(422)
          .json({ message: "Validation Failed!", data: errors.array() });
      }
     // .... do more stuff here
```

so the commented out piece was my initial try and it does not work, while only handling the response in the if statement works based on my case.  I want to funnel the new error down to my error handling middleware in my app.js file which looks like this:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  return res.status(err.statusCode).json({ errorMessage: err.message, data: err.data });
});
```

The error I get is an "Unhandled Promise Error" when using the commented out code in my controller function.  Can anyone help me understand why the returning the response immediately works but throwing the error does not?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

in this line you defined `exports.putUser = async (req, res, next)` so `putUser` must to return a `promise` because type of is `async` but you return something else

```
return res.status(422).json(
{ message: "Validation Failed!", data: errors.array() });
```

in your case you you must to remove `return`, do like this

```
res.status(422).json(
{ message: "Validation Failed!", data: errors.array() });
```

Comment: Hi Mohammed, thanks for the response!  But in this case I found that the return does not change the behavior.  What I am curious of is why the commented out part does not work (sorry for the confusion).